# Sql update column to upper lower case

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have a column called [strCustomerName]

This column has values like 'ray mantle', 'JAMES MAY', 'john DOE', 'RICHARD & Judy Miller' and so on...

I need to do an **Update** to the table to correct the case of all values in the selected column.
The Update would then set correctly the values case to 'Ray Mantle', 'James May', 'John Doe', 'Richard & Judy Miller'

Any help doing with SQL would be great. Thanks

Comment: Is the general formula you want, First letter of each word to be upper ? in other words names like O'Connel are out of luck, they much stay O'connel ?

Comment: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3655906/Dealing-With-Upper-and-Lower-Case-Data.htm

Comment: @HolmesIV Yes, general formula, to set first letter of each word to upper and the rest of the letters to lower in that word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just create a function to convert your string (or names in your scenario) to `CAMEL` case something like below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CamelCase]
(@Str varchar(8000))
RETURNS varchar(8000) AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @Result varchar(2000)
  SET @Str = LOWER(@Str) + ' '
  SET @Result = ''
  WHILE 1=1
  BEGIN
    IF PATINDEX('% %',@Str) = 0 BREAK
    SET @Result = @Result + UPPER(Left(@Str,1))+
    SubString  (@Str,2,CharIndex(' ',@Str)-1)
    SET @Str = SubString(@Str,
      CharIndex(' ',@Str)+1,Len(@Str))
  END
  SET @Result = Left(@Result,Len(@Result))
  RETURN @Result
END;
```

Once your function is created, you could then use it in your update statement as below:

```
UPDATE Customer
SET strCustomerName = dbo.CamelCase(strCustomerName)
```

You could also call the above function in the select statement directly to check if the values are going to update correctly before running the update statement above:

```
select id
      ,dbo.CamelCase(strCustomerName) as CustomerName
from Customer;
```

Hope this helps!

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/620894/1/0)